# How to map a dataframe of datetime strings in spark to a dataframe of booleans?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to basically check whether every value in my dataframe of dates is the correct format "MM/dd/yy".

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.read.csv("----")
```

However, whenever I apply the function map:

```
df.map(x => right_format(x)).show()
```

and try to show this new dataframe/dataset, I'm getting a nonserializable error.

Does anyone know why?

I've tried to debug by using the intellij debugger, but to no avail.

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.read.csv("----")
df.map(x => right_format(x)).show()
```

Expected results: dataframe of boolean values
Actual results: Nonserializable error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the non-Serializable error say something like `SparkContext is non serializable`?

Map runs in a distributed manner, and Spark will attempt to serialize and send `right_format` function def to all the nodes.
It looks like `right_format` is defined in the same scope as objects such as your `SparkContext` instance (for example, is all this in your `main()` method call?).

To get around this, I think you could do 1 of 2 things -

1. Define `right_format()` within the `map` block

```
df.map(x => {
        def right_format(elem) = {...}
        right_format(x)
    }
).show()
```

2. Define an abstract object or a trait of helper functions that includes the function def for `right_format`.

Spark will serialize this object and send it to all the nodes. This should solve the issue that you're facing.

Comment: Hey Kevin thx for the fast response! So to answer ur questions... 1. I don't remember the exact error.             2. "Where is right-format defined"...so right_format is defined in a scala class which I'm testing in a maven test class. In that maven test class I run the map operation. 3. "Where do I define the spark context instance"--so I defined that in both my test class and the class with the right_format function.  And for some clarification...1. just mapping like df.map(x => right_format(x)) has no error, but calling show on that does...why? 2. Why do I get an error in the first place?

Comment: Transformations (such as `Map`) in Spark are lazy. These are only evaluated when an Action (such as `show()`) is called (reference [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations)). So it makes sense that the error comes from the `.show()` call.

Comment: So it looks like the error happens because Spark tries to serialize the class with the `right_format` func def - but it encounters an object that can't be serialized (that is also defined in the same class). I recommend trying out #2 in my original answer.

Comment: Make that #1 in my original answer.

Comment: Ok so error has nothing to do with having two spark instances with same appname("myappname"), and same master("local")?

Comment: And in terms of answer 1 or 2, I will also run the map function in the normal scala class, so I think it might look better to do 2 so I will do that.

Comment: Ok so i fixed my error, u deserve the check man. Nice job and thx for ur help-fellow ml guy haha lol.

Comment: :-D sure thing, glad I could help!